# VSDBCMD Won't Start - Sql100DatabaseSchemaProvider can not be instantiated

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, vsdbcmd

I've followed the instructions over at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193258(v=vs.100).aspx

I've copied the deploy folder and the other dll's over to the remote machine and installed SQL Server 2008 Management Objects. However, when I attempt to run my command (real credentials stripped)

```
vsdbcmd /a:Import /cs:"Data Source=mydb;Integrated Security=false;Pooling=False;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=sa;Password=password;" /model:today.dbschema
```

I always get the error

```
The extension type Microsoft.Data.Schema.Sql.Sql100DatabaseSchemaProvider could not be instantiated.
```

I've searched around, but don't see anything that points to this. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - the server had .NET 4.0 Client Profile installed. Once I installed the full runtime, this issue went away.